# Dojo: BorderContainer how to change splitter width/height?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.layout

I'm wondering, how can I change the size of splitter in BorderContainer ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try looking at what CSS rule is responsible for that width and then change that.

Answer (score 0):

To collapse/remove the splitter completely set the gutter property to false.